# Using Kotlin and Mockito to mock functions taking vararg parameters

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, variadic-functions, powermock

I'm having trouble utilizing Powermock, Mockito, and Kotlin to mock up a return value when
the function signature that needs overriden contains varargs.

Function to mock/override:

```
public BoundStatement bind(Object... values);
```

Test File:

```
class DbSessionTest {
    var preparedStatement: PreparedStatement? = null

    @Mock
    var boundStatement: BoundStatement? = null

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        initMocks(this)
        whenever(preparedStatement?.bind(any())).thenReturn(boundStatement)

        // Also, have tried it like this
        whenever(preparedStatement?.bind(any<Array<Any>>())).thenReturn(boundStatement)
    }
}
```

The fuction in the actual code is called like so:

```
internal fun createBoundStatement(query: String, vararg params: Any): BoundStatement {
    val preparedStatement = prepare(query)
    val boundStatement = preparedStatement.bind(*params)
    return boundStatement
}
```

When I step through and the varargs are dereferenced, it turns into an `Object[]`.
When the object array contains all the same type, everything works fine, but when
it contains type `String` and type `Integer`, the mock fails to happen and `null` is
returned.

Note: I have also included `com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.any` package for their specific
`any` function and `anyVararg`, but that did not work either.

What is the proper way to mock this so that no matter the type in the Object array,
it will always return the mocked value?

Comment: what version of mockito are you using?

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild powermock v1.7.4, which has both v1.10.9 and v2.8.9 in their [build.gradle](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/blob/powermock-1.7.4/build.gradle#L35-L36)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicholas Hauschild's answer make me think about removing powermock and just going with regular mockito and junit separately and that worked. Removing powermock and Upgrading mockito to v2.18.3 fixed the issue.